# Is there a way to perform this with PHP? Static methods

Tags: php, class, methods, static, self

Looks like impossible do something like that:

```
class Service
{
    public function get($argument1, $argument2)
    {
        echo "Arguments: $argument1, $argument2.";
    }
}

class Main
{
    public function __callStatic($method, $arguments)
    {
        $method = "get".ucfirst($method);
        $arguments = implode(", ", $arguments);

        $object = self::$method;

        return $object->get($arguments);
    }

    public static function getService()
    {
        return new Service;
    }
}

$main = new Main;
$main::Service("1", "2"); // Should output 'Arguments: 1, 2.'
```

The problem is the self mess everthing, with this will be possible.

Use self::$variable, self this we have a variable in the Main context.

$object = self don't work too.

$object = clone self dont' work too.

define("method", $method);
self::method will not work because self thinks is a class constant property.

*this* can't be used.

Is there a way to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the original `$arguments` directly to [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
return call_user_func_array(array($object, "get"), $arguments);
```

Then, just make a static call to `Main`:

```
Main::service("1", "2");
```

---

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/phhqy6

Comment: Joseph, looks like a very interesting solution. But I didn't understand it completly yet. Could you write all * __callStatic* for me? I'm wondering how could I use *$object* as you wrote if the main problem is I can't get the object with the statement *$object = self::$method;*.

Comment: @GarouDan - You have to call it `$object = self::$method()`: http://codepad.viper-7.com/phhqy6